# msdeploy and setparameters.xml

Tags: asp.net, parameters, msbuild, msdeploy

I'm having issue with the SetParameters.xml file used by msdeploy.

In my website I've created a parameters.xml file which contains the following:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter name="enableRule" defaultValue="DoNotDeleteRule"></parameter>
</parameters>
```

During the build of the deployment package, this parameter is added to the setParameters.xml file, which then looks like:

```
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="mywebsite/myservice/>
  <setParameter name="enableRule" value="DoNotDeleteRule" />
</parameters>
```

Yet, when I run msdeploy (using the cmd of the package), the parameter is ignored. I've tried calling the cmd by adding the -setParamFile attribute, but that didn't make any difference...

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing the concept of [MSDeploy "parameters"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) with [msdeploy.exe arguments](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=WS.10%29.aspx). The latter contains features that cannot be specified using the former. For example "verb", "source", "dest", "enableLink", etc

Your only choice is to pass "-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule" as an actual command line arguments to msdeploy.exe (I believe tacking it onto the end of your call to the `cmd` file will also suffice)

Comment: I don't know why i was so sure that I could pass the actual arguments via the parameters file. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option -setParamFile I was using it like:
-setParamFile=file.xml and getting errors, but had success with -setParamFile:file.xml

Note the : instead of = like the doco says